# Using sed how to remove last character only in the first line

Tags: sed

How can I use `sed` to remove the last character from only the first line of a file?

Comment: it's always a good idea to give some of your test/try so explaination could be on it also and other see that your are not asking to work in their place but need help.

Comment: @blefeet  I do not see that this is to `broad`.  There are not to many answer, nor do it need a long answer.  On the other hand, this may be found by google.

Comment: @bluefeet Since the previous commented misspelled your name I figured I would post a notification to you

Comment: @Jotne Right now this post doesn't contain a question, the title is the only thing with a question the rest is just asking for an explanation which could lead to multiple answers or a long explanation, the way this is written it is not a good fit for the site.

Comment: @Sandey I voted to reopen this BUT in addition to what others have told you about you should provide a few lines of sample input and expected output.

Comment: @bluefeet, sorry for the misspelling of you name.  Only missing one vote for reopening.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can for example use this:

```
sed '1 s/.$//' file
```

#### Explanation

- `1` indicates the line in which we want to perform the action.
- given the syntax `s/text/replacement/`, we look for any character with `.` followed by `$`, which indicates end of line. Hence, we look for the last character before end of line and replace it with nothing. That is, we remove the last character of the line.

To edit the file you can use `-i.bak`.

#### Test

```
$ cat a
hello this is some text
and this is something else
$ sed '1 s/.$//' a
hello this is some tex
and this is something else
```

---

For fun, let's see how to accomplish this with `awk`:

```
awk -v FS= -v OFS= 'NR==1{NF=NF-1}1' file
```

This sets the input and output field separators (`FS`, `OFS`) as empty (same as `BEGIN{FS=OFS=""}`), so every single character is a field. Based on that, when the record is 1 (in this case, when we are in the 1st line), decrement the number of fields (`NF`) so that the last character is "lost". Then `1` is a true condition that makes `awk` perform its default action: `{print $0}`.

Comment: +1 no matter how simple/hard the question is, you always give complete answer!

Comment: hard to be better with sed  and explaination is as it should :-)

Comment: `NF=NF-1` can be written `--NF` but IIRC that will only work on some awks (e.g. not nawk?), and to remove the last char on line 1 with awk you'd really just do the equivalent to the sed command, i.e. `awk 'NR==1{sub(/.$/,"")}1' file`. +1 for the sed command and explanations.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @EdMorton . Then, isn't the current `awk` approach a good (or at least correct) way to do it? I see it is a bit overkilling, while `sed` (or its `sub()` equivalent) is quite fast, but I am guessing if "playing" with `NF` is good enough to be taken into consideration :)

Comment: Adjusting NF is something I personally just never think of and I'm not sure of it's side-effects (is it more like adjusting a field or adjusting a record?) and it will only work on some modern awks so I'd never do it myself but YMMV.